# displaying the count for of each column value in a dataset

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want to display the count of the first column, the following is a data set

[image]

Where the first column is the occurrence of year in the entire table.

Can anyone suggest the formula. I have used count(A) but its giving 1 everywhere

Answer (score 0):

`=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$8,B1)`

This will assess the count based on a criteria. Notice the absolute referencing so that the count range does not update but the criteria does...